# subset data across multiple columns

Tags: r, subset

Consider the data here:

```
X <- 1:4
Ya <- 10:13
Yb <- 2:5
Yc <- c(10,11,6,NA)

df <- data.frame(X, Ya, Yb, Yc)
```

For each `X` value, I want to extract the unique `Y` values (from `Ya:Yc`)

So I am trying to achieve an output:

```
# the first number is the X value, then the proceeding numbers are
# the unique Ya:Yc values for each row
# 1, 10, 2
# 2, 11, 3
# 3, 12, 4 , 6
# 4, 13, 5
```

I have tried using a simple `for` loop.

```
output1 <- c(NA,NA,NA,NA)

for(i in 1:4) {
  output1[i] <- c(i,as.numeric(unique(df[i,2:4 ])))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  gather(key, value, -X) %>%
  group_by(X) %>%
  distinct(value) %>%
  spread(key, value)
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [4 x 4]
#Groups: X [4]
#
#      X    Ya    Yb    Yc
#  (int) (dbl) (dbl) (dbl)
#1     1    10     2    NA
#2     2    11     3    NA
#3     3    12     4     6
#4     4    13     5    NA
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is an option using `data.table`.  Convert the `data.frame` to `data.table` (`setDT(df)`), `melt` from 'wide' to 'long' format, get the `unique` elements `by` 'X' and 'value' column, then `dcast` from 'long' to 'wide' format.

```
library(data.table)
dcast(unique(melt(setDT(df), id.var="X"),
          by = c("X", "value")), X~variable, value.var="value")
#    X Ya Yb Yc
#1: 1 10  2 NA
#2: 2 11  3 NA
#3: 3 12  4  6
#4: 4 13  5 NA
```